# Problem with location of link in Selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem. I want to click on `Zadanie 1` using Selenium here:

https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/

I tried xpath, partial links, link text and so on, but all the time I have error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:  {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/h2"}

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Zadanie 1"}
```

How can I locate this link?

```
<a href="/task_1">
  <h2>Zadanie 1</h2>
</a>
```

It's weird for me, because when I run code of @0m3r it works. but when i paste it to my project i get errors.

```
import unittest
import time
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from ASTA.Pages.HomePage import ASTA_homepage


class test_task1(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_open_task(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://asta.pgs-soft.com/")

        open_app = ASTA_homepage(driver)
        open_app.open_buggy_app()
        time.sleep(3)
        open_app.open_task1()

    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/Warpath/PycharmProjects/allegro_tests/venv/ASTA'))



class ASTA_homepage():

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def open_buggy_app(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Buggy app").click()

    def open_task1(self):

        link = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Zadanie 1")
        link.click()
```

Comment: Can you share full html/code?

Comment: https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/ you can inspect the page and Zadanie 1 button

Comment: I'm not having any issues using

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/h2').click()

on my machine. Are you using the driver directly to find the element, or another element? Add a sleep to see if it is a timing issue.

Comment: i tried to use the same code as you, with sleep, with implicitly_wait(5).... and all the time have an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Find it by link text*

*Example*

```
import time    
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/"

chrome_browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

link = chrome_browser.find_element_by_link_text("Zadanie 1")
link.click()
```

Comment: it's weird. when i run your code it works. but in my project using page object pattern i can't locate it.

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Zadanie 1"}

Comment: hmm but when i changed links in get method, and start from page with Zadanie buttons it works.

Comment: congratulation my friend @margaret have fun- see around

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Selenium method other than `find_element_by_xpath`. You can find elements of an xpath, jspath, inner HTML, etc

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

These are the available methods Selenium allows.

I have a form filling application where every element can be found by name but one of them needs to be found exclusively by xpath for some reason.

Comment: I know that, but this link doesn't have any name, id. i have only link text and xpath. but nothing work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click on that button using this below.  Also, it's always good practice to use waits when attempting to find or interact with elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# You will need to use the path for your driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Shared/Drivers/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/')

button = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[href=\"\/task_1\"]')))

button.click()
```

You can find more information regarding the use of waits here:  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: line 26, in test_open_task button = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[href=\"\/task_1\"]'))) File "C:\Users\Warpath\PycharmProjects\allegro_tests\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: